# Replace database row if the pending @Insert has the same field value

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

My Room method `addMatchUid()` is not abiding by its `OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE`. It simply adds the same database row:

[image]

Here is my data class:

**MatchedUser.kt**

```
@Entity(tableName = "matched_users")
data class MatchedUser(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "match_id") val matchId: String
)
```

**MatchedUsersDao.kt**

```
@Dao
interface MatchedUsersDao {

    @Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM matched_users WHERE :matchId = match_id LIMIT 1")
    suspend fun matchedBefore(matchId: String): Int

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun addMatchUid(match: MatchedUser)
}
```

Here is `addMatchId()` being executed:

```
val match = MatchedUser(0, matchId)
CustomApplication.database?.matchedUsersDao()?.addMatchUid(match)
```

My only guess to the problem is that the database rows arn't actually duplicates because the id is different. If that's the case, how can I ensure rows are replaced when `match_id` is the same value?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `unique` index on `match_id` to have desired behavior.

```
@Entity(tableName = "matched_users", indices = [Index(value = ["match_id"], unique = true)])
data class MatchedUser(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "match_id") val matchId: String
)
```